# Estimating Amount Of time For Tasks Running in Parallel

Tags: .net, concurrency, task, task-parallel-library

I have a list of Items, each item takes certain amount of time based on some calculation, and the time to be taken is Item Specific.
Numbers in bracket are amount of time each item will take when executed.Time is in seconds

Eg. I have 5 Items - Item1 (2), Item2(1), Item3(4), Item4(3), Item5(2).

I prepare a List comprising of items let us say the List is called List1 and has items - Item1, Item3, Item5.

Now these items are basically representing certain operations, (please assume that there is no external factor Like I/O, Processor etc impacting these items /steps)

```
foreach(var x in List1)
{
   // How to execute the items actually in Parallel 
}
```

Question1: How to actually ensure that these items run in parallel. Is using TLP (task parallel library) an option, if yes how to use it.

Question2: Now in this case when they actually run in parallel , is it safe to say that the amount of time taken will be maximum of amount of time of the Item in the list. In this case 4 seconds as Item3 is having highest among all the items of List1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question1: How to actually ensure that these items run in parallel. Is using TLP (task parallel library) an option, if yes how to use it.

Using the TPL would be the best option but it does matter whether your process is IO bound or CPU bound. In simple terms if the process is purely a CPU time consuming operation then you're CPU bound, otherwise if you you're doing IO then your IO bound bound. Here's an example of each:

```
public class IO_Item
{
    public Task Process() => Task.CompletedTask;
}

public Task ProcessAll_IOBound(IList<IO_Item> items)
{
    var tasks = items.Select(item => item.Process());
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public class CPU_Item
{
    public void Process() { }
}

public void ProcessAll_CPUBound(IList<CPU_Item> items)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(items, item => item.Process());
}
```

> Question2: Now in this case when they actually run in parallel , is it safe to say that the amount of time taken will be maximum of amount of time of the Item in the list. In this case 4 seconds as Item3 is having highest among all the items of List1.

Not necessarily. First off running in parallel doesn't necessarily mean all items at once. They may get batched, blocked or otherwise have to wait for their turn to run and would thus increase the total time. Also, remember operating in parallel is not without overhead. In terms of performance it's always best to profile a realistic test case and see what the numbers tell you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, just curious what would happen if the items are batched. One of the possibility that you have mentioned in your response, is it in this case, they will be really processed in parallel?

Comment: Well think if you have 100 CPU bound items, and only 4 cores, at most you can handle 4 items in parallel so the others will have to wait.